# Python issue with apostrophe when using replacements function

Tags: python, pandas, replace, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to replace a string that has more than one apostrophe but it's messing up the string being executed properly.

The first replacement works fine, but the second needs to replace this:
**"{u'large': u'**

Obviously I get a syntax error. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
data = pd.read_csv("output9.csv")

replacements = {',episodeNumber,title,image,excerpt,audioSource':'<div class="episode-wrap">'}

replacements = {'"{u'large': u'':'<image>'}

with open('output9.csv') as infile, open('output9-1.csv', 'w') as outfile:
    for line in infile:
        for src, target in replacements.iteritems():
            line = line.replace(src, target)
        outfile.write(line)
```

Comment: third line is not correct. you need to close it with  }

Comment: @wwii could you elaborate please? Move it above 'for line in infile'?

Comment: @Siyavashvaezafshar The third line is closed with that? Not too sure what you mean?

Comment: it is not closed look closely starts with two { and ends with one

Comment: try: `{""""{u'large': u'""":'<image>'}`

Answer (score 1):

instead of this

```
replacements = {'"{u'large': u'':'<image>'}
```

use this

```
replacements = {"{u'large': u'':'<image>'}"}
```

you didn't close `"` and `}` also you used one extra `'`

Comment: Many thanks. The output is telling me Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./test9-1.py", line 17, in <module>
    for src, target in replacements.iteritems():
AttributeError: 'set' object has no attribute 'iteritems'

Comment: I should really also mention that the original data being parsed is javascript with lots of those symbols all over it:
116,episodetitle,"{u'large': u'https://thisiscriminal.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/Bunny_art-1024x1024.png'
I need to insert a <a href> type html link in order for the particular python script pull that image link out.